# Atom editor no longer opens from command line

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source

I've been using the Atom editor on my iMac running High Sierra. I usually run it from the terminal by typing `atom`. I moved many of my apps to an external drive to free up disk space. I originally moved Atom but have since moved it back onto my startup volume.

Sometime during all this I have messed up something and now Atom no longer runs from the command line. I started Atom by double-clicking on the icon. I selected "Install shell command" from the  Atom menu.

Previously I did that so I could run atom from the command line. Well, it didn't work this time. How can I tell what that menu option actually does? When I select "Install shell command", what does Atom actually do? And how do I find out what a command does?

If I knew what the Atom command does, I could maybe fix this. Most questions I've read that pertain to this offer alternative ways to run Atom from the command line. I know how to do that, I'm trying to get things back to the way it was before my messing around caused all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as though it's running

`/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh`

but you should be able to edit your `~/.bash_config` and add the line

`alias atom="/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom"` 
then re-open terminal and you'll be able to launch atom by typing `atom [filename]`, assuming your copy of Atom is installed in the /Applications folder

Comment: Yes, I know that. But that's a work around.  I looking for the original way it was set up.  Thank though.

Comment: As I said, it looks like the original way it's setup is by running `/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh`

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened. When I looked at atom.sh it was empty which probably explains my problem. I may just have to reload Atom.  Unless someone solves this I'll accept your answer since it provided me the name and path to the .sh file.  thanks again.

Comment: This is the up to date version as of time of writing https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/1.28-releases/atom.sh

Comment: Wow. Big difference from an empty file! lol..  I might paste this into my version of atom.sh and see what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: I pasted that code into my atom.sh file and reran it. It appears to have worked fine. Now atom works from command line.  Thanks again...